# Faster way to groupby time of day in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, time, group-by, pandas

I have a time series of several days of 1-minute data, and would like to average it across all days by time of day.

This is very slow:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import date_range, Series
time_ind = date_range(datetime(2013, 1, 1), datetime(2013, 1, 10), freq='1min')
all_data = Series(randn(len(time_ind)), time_ind)
time_mean = all_data.groupby(lambda x: x.time()).mean()
```

Takes almost a minute to run!

While something like:

```
time_mean = all_data.groupby(lambda x: x.minute).mean()
```

takes only a fraction of a second.

Is there a faster way to group by time of day?

Any idea why this is so slow?

Comment: dt.time is not optimized by pandas. It takes much time convert a pandas TimeSeries to datetime.time array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your "lambda-version" and the time property introduced in [version 0.11](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/release.html#pandas-0-11-0) seems to be slow in version 0.11.0:

```
In [4]: %timeit all_data.groupby(all_data.index.time).mean()
1 loops, best of 3: 11.8 s per loop

In [5]: %timeit all_data.groupby(lambda x: x.time()).mean()
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> ignored
1 loops, best of 3: 11.8 s per loop
```

With the current master both methods are considerably faster:

```
In [1]: pd.version.version
Out[1]: '0.11.1.dev-06cd915'

In [5]: %timeit all_data.groupby(lambda x: x.time()).mean()
1 loops, best of 3: 215 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit all_data.groupby(all_data.index.time).mean()
10 loops, best of 3: 113 ms per loop
'0.11.1.dev-06cd915'
```

So you can either update to a master or wait for 0.11.1 which should be released this month.

Comment: What's your "ser"? Is it my "all_data"?
For me:
`version.version`,
`%timeit all_data.groupby(lambda x: x.time()).mean()`,
`%timeit all_data.groupby(all_data.index.time).mean()`

Gives:
`'0.11.0'`,
`1 loops, best of 3: 21.2 s per loop`,
`1 loops, best of 3: 21.7 s per loop`
`

Comment: @joeb1415 updated my answer, seems to be due to the pandas version (the numbers changed a bit since I am on another machine now). "all_data" is your "all_data".

Answer (score 2):

It's faster to groupby the hour/minute/.. attributes rather than `.time`. Here's Jeff's baseline:

```
In [11]: %timeit all_data.groupby(all_data.index.time).mean()
1 loops, best of 3: 202 ms per loop
```

and without time it's much faster (the fewer attributes the faster it is):

```
In [12]: %timeit all_data.groupby(all_data.index.hour).mean()
100 loops, best of 3: 5.53 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit all_data.groupby([all_data.index.hour, all_data.index.minute, all_data.index.second, all_data.index.microsecond]).mean()
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 ms per loop
```

*Note: time objects don't accept a nanosecond (but that's DatetimeIndex's resolution).*

We should probably convert the index to have time objects to make this comparison fair:

```
In [21]: res = all_data.groupby([all_data.index.hour, all_data.index.minute, all_data.index.second, all_data.index.microsecond]).mean()

In [22]: %timeit res.index.map(lambda t: datetime.time(*t))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.39 ms per loop

In [23]: res.index = res.index.map(lambda t: datetime.time(*t))
```

So it's around 10 times faster for maximum resolution, and you can easily make it coarser (and faster) e.g. groupby just the hour and minute..