# summing the number of occurrences per day pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set like so in a pandas dataframe:

```
                                  score
timestamp                                 
2013-06-29 00:52:28+00:00        -0.420070
2013-06-29 00:51:53+00:00        -0.445720
2013-06-28 16:40:43+00:00         0.508161
2013-06-28 15:10:30+00:00         0.921474
2013-06-28 15:10:17+00:00         0.876710
```

I need to get counts for the number of measurements, that occur so I am looking for something like this:

```
                                    count
   timestamp
   2013-06-29                       2
   2013-06-28                       3
```

I do not care about the sentiment column I want the count of the occurrences per day.

Comment: [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288636/faster-way-to-groupby-time-of-day-in-pandas)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your `timestamp` index is a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd
content = '''\
timestamp  score
2013-06-29 00:52:28+00:00        -0.420070
2013-06-29 00:51:53+00:00        -0.445720
2013-06-28 16:40:43+00:00         0.508161
2013-06-28 15:10:30+00:00         0.921474
2013-06-28 15:10:17+00:00         0.876710
'''

df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(content), sep='\s{2,}', parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])

print(df)
```

so `df` looks like this:

```
                        score
timestamp                    
2013-06-29 00:52:28 -0.420070
2013-06-29 00:51:53 -0.445720
2013-06-28 16:40:43  0.508161
2013-06-28 15:10:30  0.921474
2013-06-28 15:10:17  0.876710

print(df.index)
# <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
```

You can use:

```
print(df.groupby(df.index.date).count())
```

which yields

```
            score
2013-06-28      3
2013-06-29      2
```

---

Note the importance of the `parse_dates` parameter. Without it, the index would just be a `pandas.core.index.Index` object. In which case you could not use `df.index.date`.

So the answer depends on the `type(df.index)`, which you have not shown...

Comment: What if my index datatype is Int64Index ? I've changed it using pd.to_datetime(df["end_time"].astype('str'), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') so when I do df.dtypes it correctly returns datetime datatype however when I set end_time column as index and print index it returns Int64 datatype.

Comment: To complement this answer... to convert a datetime64[ns] to a DatetimeIndex see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690099/convert-datetime64ns-column-to-datetimeindex-in-pandas

Documentation on DatetimeIndex: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

Answer (score 22):

Otherwise, using the [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.resample.html) function.

```
In [419]: df
Out[419]: 
timestamp
2013-06-29 00:52:28   -0.420070
2013-06-29 00:51:53   -0.445720
2013-06-28 16:40:43    0.508161
2013-06-28 15:10:30    0.921474
2013-06-28 15:10:17    0.876710
Name: score, dtype: float64

In [420]: df.resample('D', how={'score':'count'})

Out[420]: 
2013-06-28    3
2013-06-29    2
dtype: int64
```

**UPDATE : with pandas 0.18+**

as @jbochi pointed out, resample with `how` is now deprecated. Use instead :

```
df.resample('D').apply({'score':'count'})
```

Comment: Resample with `how` is now deprecated. You should use `df.resample('D').apply({'score':'count'})`

Answer (score 12):

```
In [145]: df
Out[145]: 
timestamp
2013-06-29 00:52:28   -0.420070
2013-06-29 00:51:53   -0.445720
2013-06-28 16:40:43    0.508161
2013-06-28 15:10:30    0.921474
2013-06-28 15:10:17    0.876710
Name: score, dtype: float64

In [160]: df.groupby(lambda x: x.date).count()
Out[160]: 
2013-06-28    3
2013-06-29    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Huh.  Do you know why `df.index[0].date` returns `<function date>`?

Comment: Hmm. I do not. @Andy?

Comment: Well, `date.index.date` is a property on the index which is of type DatetimeIndex, while index[0] is already a Timestamp only, that does not offer the date property, but links to a method of Timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts):

```
In [21]: df.index.normalize().value_counts()
Out[21]: 
2013-06-28    3
2013-06-29    2
dtype: int64
```