# correct way to sum values of second column for all unique values of first column pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. I have a dataframe that has the days of the week in the first column and a list of values in the second. I wish to sum up the total value for each week day. so:

```
        day               values 
0   Thursday                 3
1   Thursday                 0
2   Friday                   0
2   Friday                   1
4   Saturday                 3
5   Saturday                 1
etc...
```

would become :

```
    day               values 
0   Thursday                 3
1   Friday                   1
2   Saturday                 4
etc...
```

Using [summing the number of occurrences per day pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706109/summing-the-number-of-occurrences-per-day-pandas) I achieved what I wanted:
- where the original df is called value_frame

```
values_on_day =pd.DataFrame(value_frame.groupby(value_frame.day).apply(lambda subf: subf['values'].sum()))
```

however the values and the weekdays are stuffed into one cell so that:
    print dict(values_on_day)
equals:

```
    {0: day
Friday        3
Monday        4
Saturday      7
Sunday       22
Thursday     26
Tuesday       2
Wednesday     4
Name: 0, dtype: int64}
```

I have coded a workaround by converting columns into dicts then lists and then back into a dict and converting back into a df but obviously this is not the way to do it.

Please would you show me the correct way to achieve total values for each day of the week in the original dataframe?

Comment: This should work: `df.groupby('day').sum()`, where `df` is your first dataframe.

Comment: nearly!
   `df.head()`
gives an answer with `[5 rows x 2 columns]`

`print df.groupby('day').sum()` givea an answer with `[7 rows x 1 columns]`

it looks like it thinks the values column name is a header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Primer. This is the right way to code what you want to do.
I have updated my answer to add an `index` being the weekday number.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['Thursday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Saturday'], 'values': [3,0,0,1,3,1]})
result = df.groupby('day').sum()
# Reseting the index
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
# Creating a new index as the weekday number for each day
result.index = result['day'].apply(lambda x: time.strptime(x, '%A').tm_wday)
# Renaming the index
result.index.names = ['weekday']
# Sorting by index
result.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(result)
```

Gives:

```
              day  values
weekday                  
3        Thursday       3
4          Friday       1
5        Saturday       4
```

Comment: ah! so i understand the problem a little better now. python isn't seeing values as a heading (as I thought before in my answer to Primer), its seeing it correctly as a column name, and its assigned the days as an index value! Thank you for this.

Comment: would the best way to add the numbered indexing be to do something like: `days_of_week = df.groupby('day').sum()` , where: `value_name = days_of_week.columns[0]`, and 'days_name = days_of_week.index.name` we can make a dictionary like : `new_dict = {days_name:days_of_week.index, value_name:list(days_of_week[days_name])}` and then do `new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)`  ?

Comment: I understand that you want to add an `index` to the `DataFrame` being the weekday number of each day. I update my answer in this way.

Comment: That's a better answer than I ever imagined. Thank you so much Romain!

Comment: good and simple answer. Thanks