# Convert datetime64[ns] column to DatetimeIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

One of the packages that I am working with has a pre-requisite that the index of the data frame needs to be a pandas DatetimeIndex. So, I have been trying to convert a column of the data type datetime64[ns] to DatetimeIndex with no success. Here are my attempts:

```py
import pandas as pd

my_data = [[1,'2019-05-01 04:00:00'], [2, '2019-05-01 04:01:00'], [3, '2019-05-01 04:02:00']]
test = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=['count', 'datetime'])
print(test.dtypes.value_counts())

# Attempt using pd.DateTimeIndex
test['datetime'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(test['datetime'])
print(test.dtypes.value_counts())

if isinstance(test['datetime'], pd.DatetimeIndex):
    print('Success')

# Attempt using pd.to_datetime without format string
test['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(test['datetime'])
print(test.dtypes.value_counts())

if isinstance(test['datetime'], pd.DatetimeIndex):
    print('Success')

# Attempt using pd.to_datetime with format string
test['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(test['datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s')
print(test.dtypes.value_counts())

if isinstance(test['datetime'], pd.DatetimeIndex):
    print('Success')
```

I am using the latest version of pandas - 0.25.3 and am on python 3.7. Any constructive advice is well appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast an index as a `datetime`. Use `set_index` on your column, and then typecast.

```py
import pandas as pd
​
my_data = [[1,'2019-05-01 04:00:00'], [2, '2019-05-01 04:01:00'], [3, '2019-05-01 04:02:00']]
test = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=['count', 'datetime'])
test.set_index('datetime').index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
DatetimeIndex(['2019-05-01 04:00:00', '2019-05-01 04:01:00',
               '2019-05-01 04:02:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq=None)
```

Comment: Here is what I noticed, while the code works, I have noticed that the dates are formatted incorrectly. Do you also notice this ?

```python  
import pandas as pd
from pecos.monitoring import PerformanceMonitoring

my_data = [[1,'2019-05-01 04:00:00'], [2, '2019-05-01 04:01:00'], [3, '2019-05-01 04:02:00']]
test = pd.DataFrame(my_data, columns=['count', 'datetime'])
test.set_index('datetime').index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
test.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(test.index.values, dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq=None)
```

Comment: Your code in the comment is likely working as it should be. Using `set_index` doesn't set the index of the existing `test` dataframe by default. You need to actually set it or use `inplace=True`. Your code is essentially converting `[0,1,2]` into datetimes.