# Number new occurrences per day in pandas dataframe (not count or sum)

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine I have a dataframe like the one below, where I am recording each animal I see on each day as a new row.

```
Day     Animal
1       Lion
1       Elephant
1       Giraffe
1       Elephant
2       Elephant
2       Rhino
2       Rhino
2       Lion
2       Elephant
```

I would like to create a new column that contains `1` for the first animal seen on each day (and each time that same animal is seen that day) and contains `2` for the next animal and so on. The result for the example above should look like this:

```
Day     Animal      Number
1       Lion        1
1       Elephant    2
1       Giraffe     3
1       Elephant    2 
2       Elephant    1
2       Rhino       2
2       Rhino       2
2       Lion        3
2       Elephant    1
```

Note that this is a simplified example. I am aware that in this above example, one would likely prefer to use a combination of `groupby` and `count` to count occurrences per day (e.g. [summing the number of occurrences per day pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17706109/summing-the-number-of-occurrences-per-day-pandas)). However, this is not the case in my real world case. I need to number them so I can use those numbers for something else later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use [`series.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.factorize.html) over `groupby.transform`

```
df['Number'] = df.groupby("Day")['Animal'].transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0])+1
print(df)
```

---

```
   Day    Animal  Number
0    1      Lion       1
1    1  Elephant       2
2    1   Giraffe       3
3    1  Elephant       2
4    2  Elephant       1
5    2     Rhino       2
6    2     Rhino       2
7    2      Lion       3
8    2  Elephant       1
```